# How to order an SVG visibility animation to toggle, do one image after another

Tags: svg

I want to make some images included in an SVG file toggle on and off in order. To do this, I need to know how to set my `begin` and `dur` attributes on the `animate` element.

Assuming I have images like the following:

```
<image visibility="visible" xlink:href="image1.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
   <animate attributeName="visibility" begin="0s"
 from="visible" to="hidden" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</image>
<image visibility="hidden" xlink:href="image2.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
   <animate attributeName="visibility" begin="5s"
 from="hidden" to="visible" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</image>
```

How do I get them to toggle their visibility in order, so that the first image is visible at first for 4 seconds, then turns invisible. Then the next image is visible for exactly 4 seconds, it turns invisible and the previous image is now visible for the next 4 seconds.

I would really prefer to do this with the declarative animation style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it from an example in the book [SVG Unleashed](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/svg-unleashed/0672324296/):

```
<image visibility="visible" xlink:href="image1.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <animate id="img1ani" attributeName="visibility" begin="1s; img2ani.end+1s"
 from="visible" to="hidden" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
 </image>
 <image id="img2" visibility="hidden" xlink:href="image2.gif" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <animate id="img2ani" attributeName="visibility" begin="img1ani.end+1s"
 from="hidden" to="visible" dur="5s"/>
</image>
```

Just in case anyone else has the same problem: `img1ani` begins after 1 second or 1 second after `image2ani` ends while `img2ani` begins 1 second after `img1ani` ends.

This way it toggles between the two images.

Comment: NOTE: (at least on Chrome 74) the animation from hidden to visible actually change values at duration/2, since that is when the value becomes "more visible than hidden", this might cause some weird behaviors.

Comment: For non-numerical values, it is recommended to use the set element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/set